# Jquery prop function doesn't work inside Change event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event where some of my input elements will be disabled depending on the value chosen in the radio element.

Here is my code.

HTML Code

```
<input name="choice" type="radio" id="choice1" value="firstChoice" checked />
<label for="choice1">First Choice</label>

<input name="choice" type="radio" id="choice2" value="secondChoice" />
<label for="choice2">Second Choice</label>

<input name="choice" type="radio" id="choice3" value="thirdChoice" />
<label for="choice3">Third Choice</label>

<select id="selectTest" name="selectTest" required>
  <option value="selectTest1">Test1</option>
  <option value="selectTest2">Test2</option>
  <option value="selectTest3">Test3</option>
</select>

<input id="inputTest" type="text" class="validate" required name="inputTest">
```

Jquery Code

```
$("input[name=choice]:radio").on("change",function(){

    if($("input[name=choice]:checked").val()==="secondChoice"){
        $("#inputTest").prop("disabled",true); //this works
        $("#selectTest").prop("disabled",true); // this not
    } else {
        //Do Something Else
    }
});
```

The problem is that  `$("#selectTest").prop("disabled",true);` doesn't work. It is still available when I select `secondChoice`on the Radio Input while the other is disabled(`$("#inputTest").prop("disabled",true);`).

I tried to move `$("#selectTest").prop("disabled",true);` outside the event change handler and it seems working.

Did I miss something in here? Thanks.

Btw. I am using MaterializeCSS as my CSS framework. and jquery-3.2.1.

Comment: Just tested in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk1hzmzu/) and it worked fine.

Comment: works like charm: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmBpMO

Comment: Yep, works inside a SO snippet as well.

Comment: You did reference JQuery, right?

Comment: Just tested your code works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the issue cannot be reproduced and the code is working properly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't think it should be closed, you can reproduce the error if you use MaterializeCSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just how *Materialize* works (it hides the actual `select` and uses `ul` and `li` tags to style it). So, just as you must to *load* your `select` box with `$('select').material_select();`, you must *reload* your `select` box in order to show the changes.

To do so, simply add in `$('select').material_select();` your function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select(); // initial select load

  $("input[name=choice]:radio").on("change", function() {
    if ($("input[name=choice]:checked").val() === "secondChoice") {
      $("#inputTest").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#selectTest").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#inputTest").prop("disabled", false);   // restore input
      $("#selectTest").prop("disabled", false);  // restore select
    }

    $('select').material_select(); // reload select to show changes
  });
});
```

Check this working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select(); // initial select load

  $("input[name=choice]:radio").on("change", function() {
    if ($("input[name=choice]:checked").val() === "secondChoice") {
      $("#inputTest").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#selectTest").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#inputTest").prop("disabled", false);  // restore input
      $("#selectTest").prop("disabled", false); // restore select
    }

    $('select').material_select(); // reload select to show changes
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<input name="choice" type="radio" id="choice1" value="firstChoice" checked />
<label for="choice1">First Choice</label>

<input name="choice" type="radio" id="choice2" value="secondChoice" />
<label for="choice2">Second Choice</label>

<input name="choice" type="radio" id="choice3" value="thirdChoice" />
<label for="choice3">Third Choice</label>

<select id="selectTest" name="selectTest" required>
  <option value="selectTest1">Test1</option>
  <option value="selectTest2">Test2</option>
  <option value="selectTest3">Test3</option>
</select>

<input id="inputTest" type="text" class="validate" required name="inputTest">
```

Comment: Hi Gerry, I tried your solution and it works! thanks a lot.